# Is there any way deferring PHP code?

Tags: php, deferred

Is there any way deferring PHP code?

Like in javascript we use `<script defer="defer"></script>`. Is there any way to do the same with PHP-code?

**UPDATE:**
Here is the code I use:

Info: This code is located in my sidebar and causes the website to stop for 2-3 seconds when loading. I'm trying to skip this prosess and load this code when the rest of the site has loaded.... I'm open for other coding-solutions too.

```
<div style="padding:5px;">
<?php
function currency($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount) {
$amount = urlencode($amount);
$from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
$to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
$url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amount$from_Currency=?$to_Currency";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = explode('"', $rawdata);
$data = explode('"', $data['3']);
$var = $data['0'];
return round($var,1);
}
?>


<div style="padding:2px; border-bottom:1px solid #EFEFEF;">1 USD er <?php echo currency("USD","NOK",1); ?> NOK<br />
</div>

<div style="padding:2px; border-bottom:1px solid #EFEFEF;">1 EUR er <?php echo currency("EUR","NOK",1); ?> NOK<br />
</div>

<div style="padding:2px; border-bottom:1px solid #EFEFEF;">1 GBP er <?php echo currency("GBP","NOK",1); ?> NOK<br />
</div>

<div style="padding:2px; border-bottom:1px solid #EFEFEF;">1 SEK er <?php echo currency("SEK","NOK",1); ?> NOK<br />
</div>

<div style="padding:2px; border-bottom:1px solid #EFEFEF;">1 DKK er <?php echo currency("DKK","NOK",1); ?> NOK<br />
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What would "the same" be? Because it cannot be *literally* the same, since PHP does not have the concepts of a document, of the DOM being ready, etc.

Comment: Could you give an example? You'd probably answer your own question as you try to come up with one.

Comment: This makes no sense. `<script defer="refer">` means that it is okay to proceed with loading other page elements while the script loads. PHP on the other hand is executed on the server, usually _before_ anything reaches the browser.

Comment: Check again what defer does and tell us what you are trying to achieve with php: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: Cannot remember that such a feature exists in PHP. But a simple solution would be to rethink about your code, starting to restructure it to extract the one you want to be executed "deferred" and execute it later resp. at the end. An actual deferred execution like in JavaScript makes not really much sense.

Comment: ok, here is the deal... I have a PHP code that I use that get info from Google Currency Converter. It's placed in my sidebar at the moment and it causes the site to stop in 2-3 seconds and then continue loading. So I'm trying to find a way to skip the loading process for that part and do that when the site has finished loading. I will update the question with my code. 2 min...

Comment: Then load the sidebar via an ajax request to a different php script dedicated to that task

Comment: I have it in a PHP widget to make it adustable for "non-geeks".. So I cant change the whole sidebar-code just to make this one work. Or do you have any spesific answer/suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use AJAX to load this in a separate request so that it doesn't delay the page load. However, as this is a different domain, you will have to hack around the same origin policy e.g. using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), so this can be tricky and has security implications if done badly. Try using jQuery, as per [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development/).
2. Run a cron job that retrieves this data periodically on the server and stores it in your database so it can be loaded from there.

Either way is fine, but if the data volume is large and/or the remote connection may be slow, then the cron option may be preferable.

Comment: I would use JS if I could, but I'm a bit noob, so do you have a code I can take a look at/use?

Comment: Tutorial with examples: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development/

Answer (score 6):

Only maintainable way to defer PHP code (without hacks) is trough `__destruct` method:

```
class App {

    protected $deferredStack = [];

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->runDeferredStack();
    }

    public function defer(callable $deferred){
        $this->deferredStack[] = $deferred;
    }

    protected function runDeferredStack()
    {
        array_map('call_user_func', array_reverse($this->deferredStack))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$app->defer(function(){ echo "bye"; })
// code that opens a resource here...
$app->defer(function(){ echo "closing resource"; })
// code that opens DB connection here...
$app->defer(function(){ echo "closing DB connection"; })
$app->defer(function(){ echo "hi"; })
```

Since deferred stack is executed in reverse order `stdout` would be:

```
hi
closing DB connection
closing resource
bye
```

You cal also use [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want AJAX. Briefly put:

1. Do not include the offending code in your page; put some placeholder (like a loading animation) where the code's results would appear.
2. In its place include JavaScript code that makes an AJAX request back to your server; the server handles this request by running the offending code and returning some result (possibly straight HTML).
3. The JavaScript code takes this result and incorporates it in your page, replacing the placeholder.

If you use jQuery, the convenience function [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is a good place to start.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a bit noob here... do you have a code for this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try moving those div's to footer and than move them in-place with JavaScript. Although, that will brake graceful degradation since it will stay in the footer if user has no JS. On the other hand, it will spare you from making additional request via AJAX.

If using jQuery, it would be something like this:

```
<div class="footer_calcs">
    <div style="padding:2px; border-bottom:1px solid #EFEFEF;">1 USD er <?php echo currency("USD","NOK",1); ?> NOK<br />
    </div>
    ...
</div>

<script ...>
    $(function(){
        $('.footer_calcs').children().appendTo( $('#id_of_destination_in_sidebar') ):
    });
</script>
```

---

**Another option** might be to:

1. convert value "1" of the `$from_currency` to `$to_currency`
2. store that ratio in a PHP var `$currency_ratio`
3. use `$currency_ratio` ratio for all the calculations so you don't need to make a CURL request to google for each one of them.

This way you do only one CURL call instead of 5, that should speed up things significantly.

Comment: That's totally not the issue here.

Comment: @Jon yes it is! If page loading stops in footer for a couple of seconds, that is ok since user doesn't notice that. It's a better option than AJAX, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Like it has been suggest here already, use Ajax to load the content in an  asynchronous way. But here's an example on how it works.

There are several ways to do this, but your best bet is to use a JS library. A very populair one is jQuery (maybe you're already using that?).

You can easily make an Ajax call with jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1/controller/someAction/param1',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

In this example i'm making a call to this URL: `http://127.0.0.1/controller/action/param1`. Of course, you can use any URL you want. But the point here is that you have to make sure it only returns what you want to see. So it shouldn't return the entire page (DOCTYPE and all), but just something like:

```
// This is obviously just fictional, i have no idea how your php code looks like
public function someAction($param1)
{
    $menu = $this->getPartialView('menu.phtml');
    $this->view->parse($menu);
}
```

And menu.phtml looks something like this:

```
<div>
  <div> ... content ... </div>
</div>
```

Now back to the JS code. If everything goes well, then the `success` method should get triggered. All the content will be in the variable `data`. So all you need to do now is to place that data in the right DIV. That's what this line is for: `$('.result').html(data);`. That will place the loaded content in a div with the class name `result`.

That's basically all you need to do.